# Understanding catching exceptions and doing continuations in multi-threaded code

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, exception, task-parallel-library

I'm checking a bit of work I'm doing and thought I'd get a few more eyes on it. I have code in production that's giving us trouble. It's using multi-threading and I'm relatively new to *that* area. I took the code that I believe has been the trouble and tried to isolate it down to its core and have been fiddling with my "model." This what I came up with. I'd like any feedback anyone cares to share. Thanks in advance.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(3);

        Console.WriteLine("Starting loop");

        var foo = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

        foreach (var i in foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Queueing task {0}", i);

            var j = i;
            var sl = i*1000;

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                semaphoreSlim.Wait();

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task {0} started - sleep {1} ms", j, sl);
                    Thread.Sleep(sl);
                    if (j == 2 || j == 5) throw new Exception("error");
                    Console.WriteLine("Task {0} done", j);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Caught exception {0}", j);
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    semaphoreSlim.Release();
                }
            });

            task.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Continuation: Completed {0}", j),
                                       TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

            task.ContinueWith(x => Console.WriteLine("Continuation: Faulted {0}", j),
                                       TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished loop");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: which troubles you mean? (`code in production that's giving us trouble`)

Comment: The process seems to be skipping over some members of the group represented by foo. Part of the problem, I think, was that the try/catch was originally enclosing the foreach loop. Any exceptions inside the foreach loop would kill whole loop. The task continuations were as shown here the StartNew, which I think is what you'd expect, but don't I think they were getting called if there was an exception in the StartNew due to how the try/catch was situated. Mostly, I want to know if what I have here is a proper way to catch errors and execute continuation code.

Comment: Just drawn simple sequence diagram/timeline, one "issue" I see is on `6` and `8` seconds all tasks which still queued (5,6) won't execute since "Task#5, Task#6" are waiting on `6` second and `Task#6` is left only and waiting on `8` second but I'm not sure whether this is a problem all depends on real business logic

Comment: Fair enough. I was using sleep to put a bit of time in so that I could get a reasonable sense of the sequence of things. The combination of the sleep statement and the if/throw statement are meant to represent the business process. The items are independent (i.e. changing one's data does not affect the others' data). We put in the semaphore to control the number of threads executing at any time, which we could control from the .config, so having tasks queued is the intended behavior.

Comment: Right, so on the first stage 1,2,3 wll be queued, then after 1second #1 will finish, semaphore released and #4 in, on 2 second #2 will fail, semaphore released, #5 in, on 3second #3 done&&out, #6 in, `on 4second no activity`, on 5 second 4 done&&out, `6 second no activity`,  7 second - #5 fail&&out, `8second  no activity`, 9 second 6 done&&out. **Summary**: 3 seconds of 9 (30% time) is not loaded by effective work

Comment: I see what you're saying. Each go through the "business code" probably takes about the same amount of time, I incremented the sleep amount in my example to give me a better sense of the sequence of events. IRL, if an error happens in the code, it's caught immediately, logged in the catch and then the execution goes to the finally to release the semaphore. There's no sleep to contend in the real code. I just put it there for illustrative purposes.

Comment: so what is the question then? Program pretty simple

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into this. And apologize that I couldn't be more succinct with what I was asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How does the "process seems to skip over some members" problem show up?

If you consider process complete when you see "Finished loop" in the output, the reason is that your tasks may have not yet completed.

Wait for created tasks to complete before you write "Finished loop".